# CoreOS/systemd does not respect changes to resolved.conf

Tags: cloud, systemd

I am using CoreOS in an openstack environment and I am using `cloud-config.yml` to bootstrap the host.

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
    permissions: 0644
    owner: root
    content: |
      #  This file is part of systemd.
      #
      #  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
      #  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
      #  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
      #  (at your option) any later version.
      #
      # Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
      # You can change settings by editing this file.
      # Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
      #
      # See resolved.conf(5) for details

      [Resolve]
      DNS=10.8.20.40
      # FallbackDNS=
      # LLMNR=yes
```

but this does not reflect the DNS server on first boot. If I restart the CoreOS host then it does work. How can I get the DNS changes to take hold on first boot? Is there a `systemctl` restart command I could issue?

Answer (score 0):

CoreOS does not implement all cloud-init hooks. It has however what is called `units`

For DNS setup, use a network unit like described here: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/network-config-with-networkd.html#cloud-config

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is to create your own `/etc/resolv.conf` via the `write_files` section as seen in this example [cloud-config](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-cloudinit/blob/master/Documentation/cloud-config.md#write_files)

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: "/etc/resolv.conf"
    permissions: "0644"
    owner: "root"
    content: |
      nameserver 8.8.8.8
```